# Seemingly unrelated change to code gives different results

Tags: c++, g++

gnu compiler, running from command line, using sublime text 2 with no mods.

Simple program to show run time of a recursive function that takes a 5000 index array with random numbers of uniform distribution between zero and one, and adds them (meaning you should get a value somewhere in the ball park of 2500). The below code consistently works fine and yields something reasonably close to the expected value. However, add a new line/tab to one of the couts, and everything goes to hell in a hand basket (see below).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double sumOfRandomNumbers(double arrayToFill[], int lengthOfArray){
    if(lengthOfArray == 0) return arrayToFill[lengthOfArray];
    return arrayToFill[lengthOfArray] + sumOfRandomNumbers(arrayToFill, lengthOfArray - 1);
}

double seconds(){return double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;}

int main(){

    int sizeOfArray = 5000;
    double sum = 0.0, deltaT = 0.0, array[sizeOfArray];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) array[i] = double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX);

    cout << "\nRecursive Method\n";
    deltaT = seconds();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        sum = sumOfRandomNumbers(array, sizeOfArray);
        if (i%10000 == 0) cout << i/1000 << " percent complete\n";
    }
    deltaT = seconds() - deltaT;
    cout << "\n\n\t\tRecursive method found sum to be " << sum;
    cout << "\n\t\tThis recursive calc took " << deltaT << " seconds to run.\n";

}
```

OUTPUT

```
Recursive Method
0 percent complete
10 percent complete
20 percent complete
30 percent complete
40 percent complete
50 percent complete
60 percent complete
70 percent complete
80 percent complete
90 percent complete


                Recursive method found sum to be 2466.4
                This recursive calc took 12.226 seconds to run.
```

Here is the updated code with the updates exactly as compiled. Please note the bizarre output. I've bolded the added code. If it doesn't show up or it's hard to see, this is the change

from

```
if (i%10000 == 0) cout << i/1000 << " percent complete\n";
```

to

```
if (i%10000 == 0) cout << "\n\t" << i/1000 << " percent complete\n";
```

...........................................................................

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double sumOfRandomNumbers(double arrayToFill[], int lengthOfArray){
    if(lengthOfArray == 0) return arrayToFill[lengthOfArray];
    return arrayToFill[lengthOfArray] + sumOfRandomNumbers(arrayToFill, lengthOfArray - 1);
}

double seconds(){return double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;}

int main(){

    int sizeOfArray = 5000;
    double sum = 0.0, deltaT = 0.0, array[sizeOfArray];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) array[i] = double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX);

    cout << "\nRecursive Method\n";
    deltaT = seconds();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        sum = sumOfRandomNumbers(array, sizeOfArray);
        if (i%10000 == 0) cout << "\n\t" << i/1000 << " percent complete\n";
    }
    deltaT = seconds() - deltaT;
    cout << "\n\n\t\tRecursive method found sum to be " << sum;
    cout << "\n\t\tThis recursive calc took " << deltaT << " seconds to run.\n";

}
```

OUTPUT

```
Recursive Method

        0 percent complete

        10 percent complete

        20 percent complete

        30 percent complete

        40 percent complete

        50 percent complete

        60 percent complete

        70 percent complete

        80 percent complete

        90 percent complete


                Recursive method found sum to be 1.15021e+257
                This recursive calc took 12.262 seconds to run.
```

Note how we went from a very reasonable 2466.4 to a completely ridiculous 1.15 x 10^257. No other changes were made, these numbers are extremely typical even after dozens of runs, the code you see above is the exact code that was compiled and run.

Comment: You know `arrayToFill[lengthOfArray];` is accessing an element one past the end of your array because the indexing starts at `0`.

Comment: Post titles should be related to problem. Also, please only post relevant code. No one wants to read your entire solution. When a question has a wall of code I just go look for another one to answer.

Comment: It's a good thing you tagged this *sublimetext2*, because one should always suspect the text editor when code doesn't work as expected!

Comment: He did mention he's an entry-level CS student. Good thing he's learning this now. No need to be (too) snarky; if you don't know the cause, the output is very weird.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Many thanks. I'm just starting to try developing without an IDE so wasn't sure what effect (if any) the text editor would have.

Comment: @Praetorian I appreciate the knowledge. Not so appreciative of the sarcasm. I'm sure there was a time in your programming career when you were new to compiling/running code from the command line. However, I do offer my sincere and honest apologies if my noobness irritated you (seriously, no sarcasm). I'm a military vet and I've dealt with irritating noobies before. Maybe not in an online forum, but it stands to reason that the principle still stands.

Comment: @TimBauer Maybe the sarcasm was uncalled for, and I apologize if that's the case, but I didn't find your question irritating. If anything, I found it amusing (I'm not trying to be offensive saying that) that you thought it was pertinent to mention what text editor you were using. And I've asked silly questions, still do quite often, and there'll always be someone to point out the mirth in those, all done in good spirits. Anyway, congratulations on having your first question answered on SO! Oh, and don't forget to upvote / accept answers if you find them useful.

Comment: @Praetorian Hey, if it was meant in good fun, no worries. Trouble with text is it's sometimes difficult to get the tone of what's being said. I honestly didn't know if the text editor had an effect or not. I definitely do now though. :P I'm going to have to post on here more often. Just one question, and I've learned a ton! Also, my rep apparently isn't high enough to upvote things yet. I'm going to have to sit down and figure out how to change that...

Answer (score 3):

You have an out-of-bounds access here:

```
double sumOfRandomNumbers(double arrayToFill[], int lengthOfArray){
    if (lengthOfArray == 0) return arrayToFill[lengthOfArray];
    //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return arrayToFill[lengthOfArray] + 
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           sumOfRandomNumbers(arrayToFill, lengthOfArray - 1);
}
```

This injects **[Undefined Behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)** in your program. When your program has Undefined Behavior, everything could happen, including that sometimes the program [seems to run just fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3FDYza%2446).

Comment: On both lines in fact!

Comment: @sftrabbit: Oh, right! Good catch :-)

Comment: Nice. I definitely missed that. My thanks for pointing that out. Still, any idea why the \n\t seem to cause the program to run differently? Before they were added, program was multiple times with no issues. And when I remove them, the program goes back to running normally.

Comment: @TimBauer: This is the sort of weird things that you get when your program has Undefined Behavior: it may just run fine most of the time, and then suddenly stop working. Or it could just run fine all the time, until you make a totally unrelated change, and then it will stop working. Undefined Behavior is just that: Undefined Behavior. Anything could happen.

Comment: Many thanks. I appreciate your help and your patience. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're reading void memory (`arrayToFill[lengthOfArray]`). This is undefined behaviour, so it's going screwy. Maybe you happened to hit the memory of the console, who knows. Whatever the exact reason, this isn't a bug in the compiler. It's a bug in your code.

Update:

To give more details, since `array` is the last item on the stack, the memory beyond it will often be unused and zero-initialised when the application starts (something operating systems do for security; make sure you can't read any old passwords that might have been left by another program, for example).

But if another function is called which has a local variable, it will put a value in that space (which doesn't get cleared; you're never supposed to access it, and the OS doesn't care if you read *your own* passwords).

It could be that cout's `<<` operator has some internal condition which is sometimes setting it's first local variable to a non-zero value. Maybe the first variable is `bool beganWithNewline` (contrived!), which is setting the first byte of the element you read to `1`, but because it's the most significant byte of the double this makes a huge value (ok so it would also have to set something in the fraction part but you see the point).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! :)

Comment: Awesome! Maybe it's just the nerd in me, but that explanation is ridiculously cool.